# jpg bmp png extension GET from image For URL PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How i fix this  to get Full image Name from image Folder

```
<img style="margin:10 12 12 10px" border=0 src="<?php echo $siteurl."/wallpapers/thumbs/".$show_wallpaper["wallname"]."_".$show_wallpaper["wallpaperid"].".jpg"; ?>">
```

".jpg"
 Not ONLY .jpg also echo .png or .bmp etc. if available in image folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean, but something like this?
It puts all the extensions from the array in front of the file path, and if it exists, it outputs the image.

```
$extensions_to_check = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
$dir = '/path/to/dir/';
$file_name = 'wallpaper_something';

foreach($extensions_to_check as $ext) {
   $path = $dir . $file_name . $ext;
   if (file_exists($path)) {
      echo('<img src=\'' . $path . '\' />');
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to like this.  in first its show only .jpg images only...
but i need to show also .png, .jpeg etc also from /wallpapers/thumbs/
i make like this but not work its not showing image
`$extensions_to_check = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
$dir = '/wallpapers/thumbs/';
$file_name = $show_wallpaper["wallpapername"]."_".$show_wallpaper["wallpaperid"].".";

foreach($extensions_to_check as $ext) {
   $path = $dir . $file_name . $ext;
   if (file_exists($path)) {
      echo('<img src=\'' . $path . '\' />');
   }
}`

Comment: this script only show .jpeg extension image and not show .jpg or png
 we need IF else

Comment: i add like this `<img style="margin:10 12 12 10px" border=0 src="<?php
$extensions_to_check = array('jpeg','png','JPG','jpg');
$dir = '/wallpapers/thumbs/';
$file_name = $show_wallpaper["wallname"]."_".$show_wallpaper["wallpaperid"].".";

foreach($extensions_to_check as $ext) {
   $path = $dir . $file_name . $ext;
   if (file_exists($path)) {
     
   }
}
 ?><?php  echo $siteurl."/".$path; ?>" width=128 height=96 alt="<?php echo $show_wallpaper["title"] ." Wallpapers"; ?>">`
but if show .jpg image... not show others ext images